# Fragments the right way

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying out some fragments right now. I've got a fragment with a button and when I click that button I switch to another fragment. Now when I push on the back button I return to the first fragment that's good. Now when I click again on that button a new fragment is started. So I always start a new fragment. I think thats not the way it needs to be done. Is there a better way to for example resume the already created fragment?

My code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button test = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.d("Test", "Button clicked.");
                TestFrag newFragment = new TestFrag();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class TestFrag extends Fragment {

    public TestFrag() {
        Log.d("Test","New fragment");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add your first fragment not replace it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the fragment transaction you can specify a tag for the fragment

fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment, newFragment, fragTag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

Then later you can find a fragment by tag from the fragmentManager

newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
if newFragment then is null you should create the Fragment since it wasnt found by the tag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joakim:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment, newFragment, fragTag); fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then later you can find a fragment by tag from the fragmentManager

`newFragment = fragMan.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);` if newFragment then is null you should create the Fragment since it wasnt found by the tag. If the tag isn't null you can just add and commit the new one.